# Runtime entity and Load time entity

Tags: c, storage-class-specifier

What is the difference between Runtime entity and Load time entity. And why `static` storage class are load time entity?

Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
int i=10;
static int x=i;
if(x==i)
    printf("Equal");
else if(x>i)
    printf("Greater than");
else
    printf("Less than");
}
```

The above program produce compile time error. And why we can't able to assign the value to static variable `x` through `i`?

Comment: `void main()` --> `int main(void)`

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
 static int x=i;
```

produces error, be cause, in `C`, a `const` variable is `const`-qualified, not a compile time constant. You can only use compile time constant to initialize a global static variable.

Related: `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

Then, to answer

> *difference between Runtime entity and Load time entity*

From the memory allocation point of view, the load time allocation is handled by the compiler and the runtime allocation is handled by library functions like [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc), [`calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc), [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) etc.

You can also refer [to this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31313912/2173917) for more on this.

Comment: So If I declare int a=10, The memory allocated to 'a' is done by malloc. Is it right. This is called as runtime entity.

Comment: @mohanraj No, absolutely not. When you call `malloc()`, only then malloc works. All other memory allocation is handled by the compiler.

Comment: OK. int a=10 and static int a=10. For the above two statements, when memory is allocated?

Comment: @mohanraj `static int a=10.` compile time. `int a = 10` depends on the scope. global, compile time, local, at function call, on stack.

Comment: @mohanraj You're welcome . :-) BTW, you can consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) an answer that helped you.

Comment: @SouravGhosh you should add that `static int a = 10` could very well be stored in the final binary, rather than stack allocated; if it's never modified and is initialized by constant expression.